# Which of the following rings is isomorphic with $ \Bbb{Z}_2 [x]\big/ \langle x^2 \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Which of the following ring is isomorphic with $\Bbb{Z}_2 [x] \big/ \langle x^2 \rangle  $:

- $ \Bbb{Z}_4 $
- $ \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb Z_2  $

We know that cardinality of the  ring 
$ \left|\Bbb{Z}_m [x] \big/ \langle f(x) \rangle \right| = m^n$ when $ 0 ≠ f(x) \in \Bbb{ Z}_m [x] $ and  $n=\operatorname{deg}(f(x))$.

Now we know that $ | \Bbb{Z}_2 \times\Bbb Z_2  | = | \Bbb{Z}_4 | = \left| \Bbb{Z}_2 [x] \big/ \langle x^2 \rangle  \right|=4 $ but which of the two options gives the isomorphism type of the quotient ring?

Answer (score 1):

As a group we have $0, 1, x, 1+x$ This ring has one zero divisor, namely $x$, but in $\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/2$ you have two, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. So we can rule out the direct product ring. However, the group structure is still that of the direct product. The answer is that **neither** of those is the **ring** structure you want, but the product is the **group** structure. If you want the ring multiplication on the group $\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/2$ which corresponds to this it is

$$\begin{cases} (0,1)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)\\ (1,0) = 1_R \end{cases}$$

And this is all you need, since the cross multiplication is determined by the fact that $(1,0)$ is the multiplicative identity and anything times $0_R=(0,0)$ is just $0_R$ by a basic ring theory lemma.

Comment: I suppose the OP works with the usual ring structures on all three rings. In this case I think it remained unclear whether $\mathbb Z_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[X]/(x^2)$ or not.

Comment: @user26857 I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Is it clear from your answer "*Which of the following ring is isomorphic with* $\Bbb{Z}_2 [x] \big/ \langle x^2 \rangle  $: $ \Bbb{Z}_4 $, $ \Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb Z_2  $"? I don't think so!

Comment: @user26857 my answer clearly states that in fact neither of his two candidates is the desired correct ring structure. The op simply had a false dichotomy in his head because he only considered the two group structures, but he did not realize there were multiple possible ring structures on the same group.

Comment: Well, I'm not able to see where you showed that $\mathbb Z_2[x]/⟨x^2⟩\not\simeq\mathbb Z_4$. (But I think I've said this clearly in my first comment.)

Comment: @user26857 it's in the first sentence, the group elements are $0,1,x, 1+x$. One immediately recognizes this as $\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/2$ because polynomials add like terms.

Comment: I don't think it's there, but if you say so...